# using Automapper

Tags: model-view-controller, mapping, automapper

I have a client class that I need to map to a less complexe class of clientViewModel, and here are the two classes:

```
public class client
{
public int clientRef{get;set;}
public string Title{get;set;}
public string Forename { get; set; }
public string Initials { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
Public Address address{get;set;}
 }
```

and

```
public class ClientsViewModel
{
    public int ClientRef { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }       
}
```

And this si how I mapped the model(It is just still a proof of concept)

```
        IList<ClientsViewModel> _clientsViewModelsclients = new List<ClientsViewModel>(); 

        var model =
            new Clients().Get(10);
        Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientsViewModel>();

       ClientsViewModel cv = Mapper.Map<Client, ClientsViewModel>(model);

       _clientsViewModelsclients.Add(cv);

       return View(_clientsViewModelsclients);
```

thr problem is on the view I can see the name and title but not the Address. Is there any other mapping I should be doing, t make sure that whatever is in address line 1 odf the address class is mapped to Line1 of the clientViewModel class?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings or you can create a custom resolver.. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers

Answer (score 1):

From the comments

> *Take a look here: http://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Nested-mappings or you can create a custom resolver.. http://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers*